# change focus on clicking enter javascript html form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, key, enter

I am very much new to HTML CSS and java script i have a personal query. I am creating a software in which i have few text boxes and drop downs. i want to change focus of the the text box automatically when enter button is pressed.It should travel in a specific way every time and once all text box are over it should submit automatically when enter is pressed. I am quite good in PHP so i can code the rest of the parts. Kindly help me in this please .

I have not tried anything on this so far

```
`    <table class="labelboxs">
       <tr>
<td class="name" colspan="2" style="width:219px; float:left; margin-left:20px;">
<input id="ph_number" type="text" required="" onblur="checkus(this.value)"         style="width:200px;" placeholder="Phone Number" name="uname">
</td>
<td class="name" colspan="2" style="float:left; width:219px; margin-left:20px;">
<input id="Name" type="text" required="" onblur="checkpassstr(this.value)"        style="width:200px;" placeholder="Name" name="pswd">
</td>
</tr>  `
```

kindly check it and give me a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code

```
onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('name').focus()"
```

where 'name' is the ID of the next input box.

There are probably better options using jquery, but if you're trying to keep it simple, this should work.

Comment: but when ever i press enter my form gets submitted automatically

Comment: Add this to all but the last text field `onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('name').focus(); window.event.returnValue = false;"`